# Wordpress: Call to undefined function wp_verify_nonce() in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress

I cannot use the wp_verify_nonce method in wordpress plugin.

I get the fatal error: `Call to undefined function wp_verify_nonce()`.

I did try to render public the method `private function submit_form()` without success

```
<?php

/*
 * Frontend class.
 * 
 * Method and property for frontend section.
 * 
 * @since 1.0
 * 
 */

namespace Simplestform;

class Frontend extends \Simplestform\Base {

    /**
     * Our constructor.
     * 
     * 
     */

    public function __construct( $base_dir = null ) {

        parent::__construct();

        if ( !is_null ( $base_dir ) ) {

            /*
             * Call Base function to set the base dir
             */

            $this->set_base_dir($base_dir);

        }

        /*
         * 
         * Register shortcode
         * 
         */ 
        $this->add_shortcode();
        $this->submit_form();

    }

    /**
     * Register the shortcode
     * 
     * @since 1.0 
     */

    private function add_shortcode() {

        add_shortcode( $this->get_shortcode_tag() , array ( $this , 'render_contact_form' ) );

    }

    public function render_contact_form() {

        include_once ( $this->get_base_dir().'/views/frontend/basic-form.php' );

    }

    private function submit_form() {

        if ( isset ( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ) {

            $nonce = $_POST['_wpnonce'];

            wp_verify_nonce ( $nonce , 'test_nonce_field' );

            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump ( $_POST );
            echo '</pre>';

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21014/cant-access-some-worpress-function-from-my-plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_verify_nonce()` is a Wordpress core function. Many WP functions are just not accessible at any moment.

Looking a bit into how Wordpress works my guess is that you may have to hook your function into the Wordpress sequence. Try hooking your plugin function into `admin_init`.

```
add_action ( 'hook_name', 'your_function_name', [priority], [accepted_args] );
```

Some good necesary reading: [Wordpress - Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)